# Django Delete duplicates rows and keep the last using SQL query

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I need to execute a SQL query that deletes the duplicated rows based on one column and keep the last record. Noting that it's a large table so Django ORM takes very long time so I need SQL query instead. the column name is customer_number and table name is pages_dataupload. I'm using sqlite.

Update: I tried this but it gives me no such column: row_num

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(

    '''WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 
            id, 
            customer_number , 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                    id,
                    customer_number 

                ORDER BY 
                    id,
                    customer_number 
            ) row_num
        FROM 
            pages.dataupload
    )
    DELETE FROM pages_dataupload
    WHERE row_num > 1;

    '''
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) to determine efficiently if there is a younger `DataUpload`:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

DataUpload.objects.filter(Exists(
    DataUpload.objects.filter(
        pk__gt=OuterRef('pk'), customer_number=OuterRef('customer_number')
    )
)).delete()
```

This will thus check for each `DataUpload` if there exists a `DataUpload` with a larger primary key that has the same `customer_number`. If that is the case, we will remove that `DataUpload`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem here is the performance it takes too much time. can you edit my sql query that mentioned in my question because it's giving me  no such column: row_num

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with the below query, is there any way to reset the id field after removing the duplicate?

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(

    ''' 
        DELETE FROM pages_dataupload WHERE id not in (
            SELECT Max(id) FROM pages_dataupload Group By Dial
            )


    '''
    )
```

Comment: Please *don't*. Primary keys should *not* be resetted, since that would mean old URLs that point to the old object, now point to the new one.